# Customize UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm trying to create Custom UIPickerView, something like below.. :

http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/3015/pickercustom.png

Example : 
From "8h15" to "12h15"

I am completely blind for this concept.

Please help me...any thought, idea would be appreciated.

Comment: i think its custom pikerview not datepiker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation of UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPickerView).

Comment: Thx a lot ! 
I was looking in DatePicker. 

Message me if you wanna see result code

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a DatePicker, it might be an instance of UIPickerView which has been configured that way:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using UIDatePicker. Use [PickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) instead. You can show "8h15" to "12h15" in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIPickerView control with 3 segments. Populate the predefined data on each segment.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to customize UIPickerView. For selecting the hours you should create two arrays with the values/titles u want.

```
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 170, 275, 217)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.opaque = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [pickerView release];
```

and in delegate methods

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

return 3;
    }

   - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component {
NSInteger count =   0;
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        count   =   [arrayHours1 count];
        break;
            case 1:
                    count   =       1;
    case 2:
        count   =   [arrayHours2 count];
        break;
}
return count;
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSString *title =   @"";
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        title =  [arrayHours1 objectAtIndex:row];
        break;
    case 2:
        title   =   [arrayHours2 objectAtIndex:row];
        break;
}
return title;

    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can check it :-

code here

NSDate *choosen = datePickerView . date;

```
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        //[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

        NSString *weekday = [formatter stringFromDate:choosen];

        invoiveDateTxtFld.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", weekday];
```